# Wrong result in typescript because of weak type checking and lack of code generation for runtime type checking

Tags: typescript

As mentioned that typescript enables static typing, and as you know, type checking in compilers occurs with early binding or late binding paradigm. I think typescript's transcompiler uses something like early binding style. As we know, for completing the type checking, compiler should add some extra codes to the generated objects for checking the types during runtime. As I see, typescript doesn't add extra js codes for checking types during runtime and this style made some problem for our team. for example in below code the logical result of calling m method should be `1312` or some exceptions like ClassCastException in java. but the result is something else:

```
function m(a:string){
    console.log(a+12)
}

var a:any=13
m(a as string) // result is 25
```

Should I replace typescript in our project with js because of this problem?

Comment: *"Should I replace typescript in our project with js because of this problem?"* That's entirely up to you. In this case, the *real* problem is that the author wrote `a as string`, which lies to the compiler, [asserting that `a` is a string](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#the-as-operator) when it isn't. They should have *converted* to string, not lie to the compiler.

Comment: I think the biggest confusion is about the **as** keyword. That is not a **cast** to the specified type. It is a **type assertion**, by doing that you are telling the compiler it should consider the type of a to be string (no matter what type it actually is).

Comment: Toskv and TJ Crowder are exactly correct. You need to use .toString() or JavaScript type coersion to cast a number to a string. The `as` keyword does not the variable to another type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript isn't a library, it's a language, it does not come with extra features (just pollyfil here and there), because of that there's no type enforcement at runtime.

That being said, your example doesn't do justice to the typescript complier, because if you do this:

```
var a: number = 13;
m(a as string);
```

You get an error: `Neither type 'number' nor type 'string' is assignable to the other`.
Even with a more complex example:

```
interface A {
    a: number;
}

interface B {
    b: string;
}

function echoNumber(a: A): number {
    return a.a;
}

console.log(echoNumber(<A> { b : "str" }));
```

You get the same error.

So typescript works, and it works great, but you're just not using it right (at least in your example) because if you use `any` then you just might as well work directly in javascript, the whole point of typescript are the types and not the use of `any` (only when you must).

Comment: Yes, But I think existence of `any` type, needs some extra codes for runtime type checking. And without this, developers are able to by pass the type checking phase

Comment: @Пуя But that's the runtime of the actual language (javascript), and as typescript as a philosophy is just a language, then you don't get to have run time type enforcement. But you can implement that yourself. Also, make sure that developers don't use `any` when it's not appropriate.

Comment: +1 to Nitzan. The `any` type is specifically designed to allow people to drop into dynamic JavaScript within their TypeScript program. There is no reason to use it routinely and you can use `noImplicitAny` to avoid accidental usage. Don't use a hammer to fit a window and then complain you cracked the glass.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately for these cases, an emphasis is put on efficiency when compiling TypeScript to Javascript. That is, code that is not certainly necessary -- for example, the `__extend` or `__decorate` functions -- is omitted from the output. While *lying* to the compiler is not something that should be handled, runtime type errors can indeed sometimes arise from real use cases as well.

However, I would find this to be a weak reason for leaving *all* the advantages TypeScript provides, one of which happens to be an elegant solution to such runtime type mismatches: [decorators](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Decorators.md). Especially when used in conjuction with [reflect-metadata](https://github.com/rbuckton/ReflectDecorators).

If you were to include `m` as a method of a class, you could use a [method decorator](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Decorators.md#method-decorators) to ensure values of the correct types have been passed in at runtime:

```
function TypeCheck(
    target: any,
    propertyKey: string,
    propertyDescriptor: PropertyDescriptor
): any {
    var originalMethod = target[propertyKey].bind(target);
    var paramTypes = Reflect.getMetadata("design:paramtypes", target, propertyKey);

    // Return a new property descriptor for the decorated method.
    return {
        value: function () {
            // Check argument types.
            for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                switch (paramTypes[i]) {
                    case String:
                        if (!(arguments[i] instanceof paramTypes[i]) && typeof arguments[i] !== "string") {
                            throw new TypeError(`Expected argument ${i} to be of type 'string'.`);
                        }
                        break;

                    case Number:
                        if (!(arguments[i] instanceof paramTypes[i]) && typeof arguments[i] !== "number") {
                            throw new TypeError(`Expected argument ${i} to be of type 'number'.`);
                        }
                        break;

                    case Boolean:
                        if (!(arguments[i] instanceof paramTypes[i]) && typeof arguments[i] !== "boolean") {
                            throw new TypeError(`Expected argument ${i} to be of type 'boolean'.`);
                        }
                        break;

                    default:
                        if (!(arguments[i] instanceof paramTypes[i])) {
                            throw new TypeError(`Expected argument ${i} to be of type '${paramTypes[i].prototype.toString.call(paramTypes[i]).toString()}'.`);
                        }
                        break;
                }

            }

            // Call original method.
            return originalMethod.apply(target, arguments);
        }
    };
}
```

```js
class Foo {
    @TypeCheck
    public m(a: string) {
        console.log(a + 12);
    }
}

var foo = new Foo();
foo.m(13 as any); // Will throw TypeError.
```

---

IMO, this offers the most elegant solution at the cost of some additional one-time setup. Yes, the `TypeCheck` decorator looks bloated, but some types just require additional checking, because:

```
"some string" instanceof String; // false
```

... and reflect metadata will provide wrapper objects as type information for primitives as well.

Answer (score -1):

You are confusing `.toString()` with `as string`.

The error you are getting has nothing to do with TypeScript. It is a JavaScript error. If you add a `number` with a `string` that can be cast to a `number`, JavaScript will cast the `string` to a `number` and add them.

You can solve this problem by simply using the correct types:

```
function m(a: string){
    console.log(a + "12")
}

var a: string = "13".
m(a) // result is 1312

var b = 13.toString();
m(b) // result is 1312

var c = 13;
m(b.toString()) // result is 1312

var d = 13;
m(d) // Combile Error

var e = "13";
m(3) // result is 1312
```

Additionally you can use JavaScript runtime type checking along with Typescript type guards.

```
function(a: string | number) {
    If (typeof a == 'number') {
         console.log('13' + a.toString());
    } else {
         console.log('13' + a);
    }
}
```